# Create Flask Restx endpoints without namespaces

Tags: python, flask, flask-restx

I'm working in the redesign of an API with Flask using Flask-restx, but I've a problem: We need a legacy version of the API that accepts the old urls, for compatibility reasons, but I'm not understanding how to do this since flask-restx requires a namespace to be declared.

Urls should be something like this:

```
{{host}}/api/v1/art/savegallery <- new one
{{host}}/savegallery <- legacy
```

In Flask I've something like this:

app/**init**.py

```
db = SQLAlchemy()
migrate = Migrate()
cors = CORS()


def create_app(config_class=DevelopmentConfig):
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object(config_class)

    db.init_app(app=app)
    migrate.init_app(app=app, db=db)
    cors.init_app(app=app)

    from app.api import api_bp, legacy_bp
    app.register_blueprint(api_bp, url_prefix='/api/v1')
    app.register_blueprint(legacy_bp)

    return app
```

/app/api/**init**.py

```
api_bp = Blueprint('v1', __name__)
legacy_bp = Blueprint('legacy', __name__)

api_v1 = Api(
    app=api_bp,
    version='1.00',
    title='Art',
    description=(
        "API"
    ),
)

api_lgc = Api(
    app=legacy_bp,
    version='1.00',
    title='Art Legacy',
    description=(
        "API Legacy"
    ),
)



from app.art.routes import art_ns
api_v1.add_namespace(art_ns)
api_lgc.add_namespace(art_ns)
```

app/art/routes.py

```
art_ns = Namespace(name='art', description='Art Storage')
#artlegacy_ns = Namespace(name='legacy', description='Art Storage')


@art_ns.route('/savegallery')
class GalleryAPI(Resource):
    def get(self):
        try:
            #data = request.json
            data = {}
            return {"foo":"bar"}, 200
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            return {"error": "Something happened"}, 500
```

With this I can access correctly to `{{host}}/api/v1/art/savegallery` but I'm not finding a way to declare the legacy one, since creating an url this way would require at least the namespace part of the url. Does Flask-restx has a way to declare those URLs and/or redirect the flow to the new ones?

Comment: my suggestion would be to try FastAPI instead of flask Restx try FastAPI

Answer (score 0):

For anyone wondering how did I solve this, I just made a little trick:

/app/api/**init**.py

```
legacy_bp = Blueprint('legacy', __name__)

api_lgc = Api(
    app=legacy_bp,
    version='1.00',
    title='Art Legacy',
    description=(
        "API Legacy"
    ),
)

@legacy_bp.route('/savegallery/', methods=['POST'])
def saveGallery():
    return redirect('/api/art/savegallery/', code=307)
```

With this I drop the Namespace from the legacy API, and just declare every URL to redirect to the required one. It seems to work for now, but I'm not sure if this is the best solution, or if it might be something better, but for the moment this seems to be the answer.